# Curvature of the tautological line bundle of a projectivized vector bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a holomorphic Hermitian vector bundle and $\mathcal{O}_E(1)\to \mathbb{P}(E^*)$ the tautological line bundle over the projectivization of $E^*$. In Demailly's *Complex Analytic and
Differential Geometry* page 283 it gives a formula for the curvature of $\mathcal{O}_E(1)$ using local coordinates.

[image]It seems that we have a decomposition into horizontal and vertical components which looks like
$$\Theta(\mathcal{O}_E(1))_a=\langle R^E(a),a\rangle +\Theta(\mathcal{O}(1))$$
where $R^E$ is the curvature tensor of $E$ and $\Theta(\mathcal{O}(1))$ the curvature of the regular $\mathcal{O}(1)$ restricted to the fiber $\mathbb{P}^{r-1}$.

- Is my interpretation correct?
- Is there a coordinate free formula for this curvature?